# Bathroom light switch

Tags: wiring

Quick question.  In my bathroom I have a 2 switch electrical box.  One switch is a dimmer and the other controls the fan.  I need to replace the dimmer switch with another dimmer switch.  I connected the black wires and everything works fine but there is a ground wire on the new dimmer switch (no ground wire from the old dimmer) and I don't know where to hook the new ground wire up to?  Do I hook it up to the ground screw part on the fan switch (that would have the fan ground wire and the dimmer ground wire).  Do I not need the ground wire for the new dimmer?
Thanks!

Comment: If you want further and more specific guidance, take a picture or draw a diagram that shows the current wiring.

Answer (score 2):

Some dimmers use the ground to trickle a small amount of current for normal operation. If yours is working without it connected, I would say it doesn't fall into this category (although you could provide the model name/number to be certain).

Most likely the ground connection is there simply because all residential switches, receptacles, etc. require a ground these days.

It sounds like a ground wire is available in your switch box, but it is going to your fan's switch. **No, you cannot double-tap the ground screw on your other switch.** You need to use some form of wire connector to make what is called a **pigtail** to connect the ground from each switch to your ground wire in your switch box.

**Illustration of the pigtailing concept**
[image]

Comment: +1 But note that the illustration is **not** for a switch but an outlet. It is meant to demonstrate the use of pigtails in general, not the wiring described in this particular question.

Comment: @bib, Yes, thank you, I should have made that more clear.

Comment: Thanks so much.  It's a Cooper dimmer, model #TI06I-W-K-L

Comment: @Kelly, I see no notes about the ground being used for operation, but you should still connect it from a safety and code-compliance standpoint.

Comment: I'm confused about the pigtailing.  I'm not sure how to take the one ground wire that is connected to the fan switch and use that to make another wire available to use on the dimmer side.  Is there a video I can watch?  I think I'm making it more complicated in my mind.

Comment: The ground must also connected be to the receptacle box, which is not shown in this illustration.

Comment: @gregmac true only for metallic boxes

Comment: @Kelly http://youtu.be/pvmD0qjGUBM this shows the concept, but does not apply directly to your setup.

Comment: @mjohns Well, there are some plastic boxes that do as well (usually with a metal strip that connects to the screws the fixture attaches to). Basically if there is a ground screw on the box, it must be connected to ground. The OP doesn't understand how to connect a pigtail, so the diagram's assumption that it's a plastic box would, in the worst case, guide someone to a dangerous situation with an ungrounded box.